# How to test the appStoreReceiptURL in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

I developed one app(free app) and uploaded it to Apple store, right now i want to know if the app is installed from app store or local pkg file. So i will use the code as below:

```
    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
    if (!receiptData) {
        [NSException raise:@"MacAppStore Receipt Validation Error" format:@"Failed to fetch the MacAppStore receipt.", nil];
    }
```

When  receiptData is nil then i can know the app is installed from local pkg file, is that right?  And i also want to verify this code without submit this new change to Apple store, is there any one can help?
Thanks